# jquery datatable serverside return Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: jquery

```
         this.$('#tblRoles').dataTable({
                    "bAutoWidth": true,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { "mDataProp": "Code", },
                        { "mDataProp": "Title", }
                    ],
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": '/FunzHouse/Roles.aspx/Menu',
                    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                        $.ajax({
                            "dataType": 'json',
                            "type": "POST",
                            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            "url": sSource,
                            "data": '',
                            "success":
                            function (data) {
                                fnCallback(JSON.stringify(data.d));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

I had see the data return correctly in browser, but why it can't be populate into jquery datatable? data example as below
[{"Code":"0000","Title":"Home"},{"Code":"1000","Title":"Profiles management"}]"

```
data:
Object {d: Array[2]}
 d: Array[2]
  0: Object
  1: Object
}
```

data.d:
[ Object, Object ]

**UPDATE 1:**

```
this.$('#tblRoles').dataTable({
                    "bAutoWidth": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        {
                            "sTitle": "test", "mDataProp": "Code"
                        },
                        {
                            "sTitle": "test", "mDataProp": "Title"
                        }
                    ],
                    "sAjaxSource": '/FunzHouse/Roles.aspx/Menu',
                    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                        $.ajax({
                            "dataType": 'json',
                            "type": "POST",
                            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            "url": sSource,
                            "data": '',
                            "success":
                            function (data) {
                                debugger;
                                var feed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.d));
                                fnCallback(_.flatten(feed));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

no idea why it is still not working, keep getting length of undefined, what actually i doing wrong?

**Update 2:**
 Ok, I change another method, not using sAjax, and it work great, guess that I cant use sAjax to populate the data

```
 generateMenu: function () {
            var that = this;
            var _RolesMenu = new RolesMenu();
            _RolesMenu.fetch({
                type: "POST",
                data: '',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                success: function (Menu) {
                    that.appendMenu(Menu);
                }
            });
        },
 appendMenu: function (data) {
            var that = this;

            var feed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            var oTable = $('#tblRoles').dataTable({
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bAutoWidth": true,
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "sTitle": "Code", "mDataProp": "Code", },
                    { "sTitle": "Title", "mDataProp": "Title", },
                ],
                sAjaxSource: "",
                sAjaxDataProp: "",
                fnServerData: function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                    fnCallback(_.flatten(feed[0]));
                },
            });
        },
```

Comment: your callback call `fnCallback(JSON.stringify(data.d));` seems to be wrong. you might need `fnCallback(data);`

Comment: I had try data, data.d, json.parse(data), it keep return length undefined

Comment: can you try adding `console.log(data)` before `fnCallback` and see what is printed in the browser console

Comment: I had update, it return object, it accept object, right? If I _.flatten the data, it also not working, it keep telling that the length is not define